# r rearrange rows by Id

Tags: r, transform

Suppose if this is my dataset

```
  Id    Name     Score     Fear     Satisfaction
  1     A        10        NA       NA
  1     B        11        NA       NA
  1     A        NA        23.2     NA
  1     B        NA        34.1     NA
  1     A        NA        NA       42.11
  1     B        NA        NA       31.19
```

How can I cleanup this dataset such that all rows are aligned correctly like this below and there aren't too many unnecessary NAs like this below

```
 Id    Name     Score     Fear     Satisfaction
  1     A        10        23.2     42.11
  1     B        11        34.1     31.19
```

I apologize if I was unable to explain this more accurately but I assume the example should help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `dplyr`, `df %>%
  group_by(Id, Name) %>%
  summarise_all(na.omit)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have equal number of non-NA values per group and per column as shown in the example, we can`group_by` `Id` and `Name` and remove `NA` values

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%  group_by(Id, Name) %>%  summarise_all(na.omit)

#     Id Name  Score  Fear Satisfaction
#  <int> <fct> <int> <dbl>        <dbl>
#1     1 A        10  23.2         42.1
#2     1 B        11  34.1         31.2
```

Comment: that was perfect , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a  limited number of columns, then I believe this is the best way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <table_name> 
WHERE 
       Score IS NOT NULL
   AND Fear IS NOT NULL 
   AND Satisfaction IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Not good at SQL: What does `Score IS NOT` do? I also think this might be inefficient if you have so many conditions.